# Ipad icon size Ipad setting ios 5-7 29pt 1x 2x - iPad spotlight ios 7 40 pt - iPad app ios 7 76 pt

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to understand the icon size for iPad.

- Ipad setting iOS 5-7 29 pt 1X size ?
- Ipad setting iOS 5-7 29 pt 2X size ?
- Ipad spotlight iOS 7 40 pt 1x size ?
- Ipad spotlight iOS 7 40 pt 2x size?
- Ipad app iOS 7 76 pt 1x size ?
- Ipad app iOS 7 76 pt 2x size ?

Answer (score 4):

The Apple Developer portal gives a full list of icons sizes for all iPads and iPhones

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

The following link shows all of the required and optional icon sizes for the different iOS versions

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/qa/qa1686/_index.html

You need to remember that the retina images are twice the size of the non retina images so a non retina image of 29px by 29px named icon.png would have a size of 58px by 58px for retina and be named icon@2x.png

The @2x part allows iOS to understand that this is the retina image and display it on a retina screen.

Comment: i don't understand very well this link, sorry. where is the size of iPad setting iOS 5-7 29 pt 1x ? and what about Ipad setting iOS 5-7 29 pt 2X size ?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper-Italy please see update to the post with a link to the Q&A.

Comment: All of Apple's helpful charts do not do the obvious 29pt x 2 = ?px and has ? filename.  Put that in a chart, Geniuses.  [edit] That was written in anger, guys, sorry about that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

This icon size is in Points. If you are using preview then click on Adjust size you can custom the image size. This 1X is for regular display (non retina)and 2X is for Retina display.

Comment: I need the px size for example 76x76  iOS 5-7 29 pt 1X size

Comment: 1X and 2X only represents if its retina or non retina display. Pt is the measure of length/widht (Size) e.g iPhone 4 screen 320x480 pts, whereas pixels are for resolution.I will recommend you to open image of your icon in preview, go to Tools->Adjust Size. Under it you will find size and resolution, put what ever "size 76x76" and "resolution 29" you wants.